# Como hacer pública las variables?

Tags: javascript

Si tengo variables dentro de muchas funciones, como por ejemplo:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main);
function main() {
  var divcualquiera = document.getElementById("divcualquiera");
  divcualquiera.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (a) clearTimeout(a);
  });

  function algo() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var a = setTimeout(function() {
        // Hacer algo
      }, 400);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="divcualquiera"></div>
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la variable `a`, la pueda usar desde la función `main`?, sin usar

```
window.algo = a;
```

Comment: La pones en contexto global, es decir afuera de cualquier función, método, ciclo, condición, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",main);

var a = setTimeout(function(){
   // Hacer algo
  },400);

function main(){
  var divcualquiera = document.getElementById("divcualquiera");
  divcualquiera.addEventListener("click",function(){
    if(a) clearTimeout(a);
     console.log('algo');
  });
}

function algo(){
  setTimeout(function(){    
    },1000);
  }
```

```html
<div id="divcualquiera" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: red;"></div>
```

Tienes que declarar por fuera de las funciones.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que crear la variable **a** por fuera de la función. 
Todas las variables que creas adentro de una función (scope) no pueden ser utilizadas por fuera al menos que se pasen por referencia al retornar algún valor.
Ahora si creas una variable por fuera de la función (scope), esta si puede utilizar la variable.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main);
function main() {
  var a, divcualquiera = document.getElementById("divcualquiera");
  divcualquiera.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (a) clearTimeout(a);
  });

  function algo() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      a = setTimeout(function() {
        // Hacer algo
      }, 400);
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Define la variable **a** en main() y no en algo();